# Image visualization in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap

The image I uploaded to assets looks like this in assets detailer, but when I visualize it, I get a completely black image. I do not know why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization

Comment: thanks a lot,I tried something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the range of values. You can set it manually or select a predefined.

[image]